# DLLImport type problems

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm trying to import a C DLL into my C# project.
The **.h** code looks like this:

```
 _declspec(dllexport)   LRESULT CALLBACK SensFindDeviceW(LONG n, LPWSTR pwszMask, PSENSDEVICEW pDevice);
```

the _SENSDEVICEW struct:

```
typedef struct  _SENSDEVICEW
{
    WCHAR       szSerialNo[32];
    WCHAR       szDeviceID[32];
    LONG        nIndex;
} SENSDEVICEW, * PSENSDEVICEW;
```

So what I have done in **C#** until now is using the DLLImport:

```
[DllImport("dll/UFTAccess.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern unsafe long SensFindDeviceW(long n, String pszMask, SENSDEVICEW pDevice);
```

Defining a struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
unsafe struct SENSDEVICEW
{
    public char[] szSerialNo;
    public char[] szDeviceID;
    public long nIndex;
}
```

And trying to use it in a method:

```
SENSDEVICEW myDevice = new SENSDEVICEW();
myDevice.szSerialNo = new char[32];
myDevice.szDeviceID = new char[32];         
        long test =  SensFindDeviceW(1, "", myDevice);
```

With this a get *System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeArrayTypeMismatchException*.

If I don't initialize the arrays I get a stack imbalance error.

I already tried using stringbuilder (which doesn't work) and marshalling the char-arrays like this:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
string szSerialNo;
```

but it results in a stack imbalance.

Maybe anyone of you has an idea what else I can try to get the dll to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following issues:

1. `LRESULT` is a pointer sized signed integer. That's `IntPtr` on C#.
2. `LONG` is a macro that expands to `long`. And on Windows, C++ `long` is a 32 bit signed integer. So on the C# side you need to use `int`.
3. The struct declaration is wrong (see below). And you fail to pass the struct by reference.
4. The macro `CALLBACK` means that the function is `stdcall`.
5. There is also no need at all for `unsafe`. You should remove that.

The code should be:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SENSDEVICEW
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
    public string szSerialNo;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
    public string szDeviceID;
    public int nIndex;
}

[DllImport("...", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Stdcall, 
    CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern IntPtr SensFindDeviceW(int n, string pszMask, 
    ref SENSDEVICEW pDevice);
```

Finally, I am assuming that `pszMask` is an input parameter. And hence `string` would be correct. However, the C++ code declares it as `LPWSTR` when an input parameter ought to be `LPCWSTR`. You might like to check the semantics of this parameter. It certainly feels like an input parameter in which case the C++ coder was a little sloppy.

Comment: thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu, it's working fine :) It really makes more sense now. And yes, pszMask is an input parameter.